# HttpServlet in Vaadin 7 app

Tags: jsp, servlets, vaadin

Is it possible to have HttpServlet (with forwarding to jsp page) in Vaadin 7 application? If yes - please give an example how to do it. I failed to make it work.

My web.xml:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/blablabla/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

MyServlet:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/doc/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

When I go to http://localhost:8080/blablabla/ I see following error:

[failed to load bootstrap javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMrwG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding second `<servlet-mapping>` to one of the servlets

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/VAADIN/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

For more details check this link:

https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/application/application-environment.html#application.environment.servlet-mapping.sub-paths